# Asymptotics of the Sample Inverse Covariance Matrix

Tags: asymptotics, precision-matrix, asymptotic-covariance

[This](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81152719.pdf) paper provides the asymptotic normal distribution of the sample covariance matrix $\hat\Sigma$ under some fairly general conditions. Are there any resources which discuss similar results for the sample inverse covariance matrix $\hat\Sigma^{-1}$?

Comment: The inverse is a differentiable function at any non-singular matrix, so if $\hat \Sigma$ is consistent and asymptotically Normal and the limiting $\Sigma$ is non-singular the delta method implies the same for $\hat \Sigma^{-1}$. Is that good enough?

Comment: @ThomasLumley That should work. I was hoping to find an easy to cite source, trying to save room in a paper.